# Get preference store of a plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 plugins let say

```
Plugin A 
Plugin B
```

Plugin A depends on plugin B and A has Preference Page

Inside plugin B I want to have the preference store of A as well

When I call

```
IPreferenceStore store = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
```

from plugin B to get the store of A , I get cycle detected, because A depends on B and B also depends on A to get the preference store

Is there any way I can get the preference store of A inside plugin B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```java
IPreferenceStore prefs = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "plugin id");
```

to get the preference store for a plugin without referencing code in the plugin.

Comment: Why on earth the preferenceStore is dependent on the eclipse.ui classes? This is so nonsense! I'm trying to isolate my plugins dependencies, and i MUST include all the eclise.ui just to access a PLUGIN's preferenceStore? omg...

Comment: @marcolopes I'm not an Eclipse designer so I can't answer that. There are actually two level of preferences in Eclipse, a lower level in `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` and then this higher level in `org.eclipse.ui.preferences`. For some things it is possible to just use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` level.

Comment: Thanks! org.eclipse.core.runtime.Preferences is totally deprecated and does not even work... :\ Strange thing is i have to extend AbstractUIPlugin to acess the IPreferenceStore...

Comment: @marcolopes I was thinking of things like org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.InstanceScope and org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.IEclipsePreferences

Comment: Oh i see! I investigated those classes and implemented a NEW preferenceStore for values with no UI dependencies! Thanks a lot!